# Read text file into object

Tags: c#, file, text, nullreferenceexception, formatexception

After hours of struggle, I need to read text file into Object. **I need to skip the first 15 lines** in my file but I keep getting **Format Exception**. Please help me. I still have a lot to learn.

> Exception is => System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. 
>      at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) 
>      at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) 
>      at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value) 
>      at PostTicketProject.TicketHelper.LoadData(Ticket[][]& ticket, String[] fileLines) in D:\CleanTicket\PostTicketProject\PostTicketProject\Ticket.cs:line 139

```
public void LoadData(ref Ticket[][] ticket, string[] fileLines)
    {                            
        try
        {

            //split each line into many columns using single white space, ignore tabs and double white space

                var data = fileLines[i].Replace("  ", string.Empty).Replace("\t", string.Empty).Split(' ');

                for (int i = 15; i< fileLines.Length; i++)
            {
                //split each line into many columns using single white space, ignore tabs and double white space

                var data = fileLines[i].Replace("  ", string.Empty).Replace("\t", string.Empty).Split(' ');

                for (int j = 0; j < fileLines[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    ticket[i][j] = new Ticket //this line throws format exception
                    {
                        ErrCode = Convert.ToInt32(data[j]),
                        DefectName = data[j],
                        Action = Convert.ToInt32(data[j]),
                        JudeTime = data[j],
                        UserName = data[j],
                    };
                }
            }                  
        }
        catch (FormatException FEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception is => {0}", FEx);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException NRefEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception is => {0}", NRefEx);
        }
    }
```

**line that read text file** can read and print out the content. Seems no issue here

```
try
        {
            fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\postTicket\repairTicket_post.txt");
        }
        catch (IOException IOEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to load file... Exception is => {0}", IOEx);
        }
```

**my file structure is below**

pin start date time = 2019-03-14-01-45-05

pin end date time = 2019-03-15-02-47-05

ups star date skip = 19

operator name = ups

.
.
.

star number = 12

0 [#]pass 0 2019-03-15-02-47-05 userName

0 [#]pass 0 2019-03-15-02-47-05 userName

0 [#]pass 0 2019-03-15-02-47-05 userName

400000 [#]Missing[@]image 1 2019-03-15-02-40-05 userName

8000 [#]Offset[@]image 1 2019-03-15-02-46-10 userName

0 [#]pass 0 2019-03-15-02-47-05 userName

*Thanks for all your help*

Comment: The formatexception means that the string can't be parsed to an int, so 'data[j]' is propably a letter or an empty string in some instances. where do you get your nullreferences ? exceptions always have a stacktrace that points to the origin of the exception

Comment: The inner `while` loop will just loop forever so that's part of the problem. Get rid of it and use `for (int i = 15; ...)`. Beyond that, we need to know an example of a line that fails.

Comment: Could, please, you provide an example of the *file's content* (with 15 first records skipped)? It seems that you parse it in a wrong way.

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the line which throws the exception and step through the code while it runs.  You'll see clearly what's going on.

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Comment: @DmitryBychenko here is my file structure. I need to skip all 15 lines that start with "#".  `# pin start date time = 2019-03-14-01-45-05
# pin end date time = 2019-03-15-02-47-05
# ups star date skip = 19
# operator name = ups 
.
.
.
# star number = 12
0 [#]pass 0 2019-03-15-02-47-05 userName
400000 [#]Missing[@]image 1 2019-03-15-02-40-05 userName
8000 [#]Offset[@]image 1 2019-03-15-02-46-10 userName`

Comment: @Cheda: could you please, add a relevant (with data samples) *extract* from the file into the question?

Comment: Not sure who voted to close, but... while there are a bunch of obvious mistakes in there, as far as I can tell this does meet the requirements for a question seeking debugging help. Besides the rather simple to derive `Ticket` data storage class, the code is complete and seems compilable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a few mistakes in your code. I'll go threw it and explain what I find odd.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i< fileLines.Length; i++)
{
    while (i > 14)
    {
```

I think you intended to write `if (i > 14)` because now as soon as you reach line 15 you will be stuck in an endless loop. As an alternative to the `if` you could just initialize `i` with `14`.

```cs
var data = fileLines[i].Replace("  ", string.Empty).Replace("\t", string.Empty).Split(' ');
```

I'm guessing you just want to remove spaces and tabs at the beginning and/or the end of the line. In that case you could use `Trim()`/`TrimStart()`/`TrimEnd()` but I might be mistaken in which case your `Replace`s are the best solution.

```cs
for (int j = 0; j < fileLines[i].Length; j++)
```

In this for loop you want to loop over the split strings in `data`, but you are using `j < fileLines[i].Length` as your condition. this will run the for-loop for the amount of characters in the line and not the amount of split substrings. For that to work you need iterate over the `data` array like this: `i < data.Length`.

```cs
ticket[i][j] = new Ticket
{                                                                                               
    ErrCode = Convert.ToInt32(data[j]),
    DefectName = data[j],
    Action = Convert.ToInt32(data[j]),
    JudeTime = data[j],
    UserName = data[j],                               
};
```

In this segment you are creating your `Ticket`. The problem is that first you didn't create the inner array which most likely caused your `NullReferenceException` and secondly you are always using the same substring. Which in the unlikely case that your `ErrCode`, `DefectName`, `Action`, `JudeTime` and `UserName` are **all number and the same** is correct, but that is probably not what you intend. The solution would be to use a 1-dimensional array instead of the 2-deimensional one and not iterate over the spit substrings, but instead create the object there with the `data` array.

Updated code:

```cs
public void LoadData(ref Ticket[] ticket, string[] fileLines)
{                            
    try
    {

        //to read and store the text file data in the ticket object

        ticket = new Ticket[fileLines.Length];

        for (int i = 14; i < fileLines.Length; i++)
        {
            //split each line into many columns using single white space, ignore tabs and double white space

            var data = fileLines[i].Replace("  ", string.Empty).Replace("\t", string.Empty).Split(' ');

            ticket[i] = new Ticket
            {                   
                ErrCode = Convert.ToInt32(data[0]),
                DefectName = data[1],
                Action = Convert.ToInt32(data[2]),
                JudeTime = data[3],
                UserName = data[4],
            };
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException FEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception is => {0}", FEx);
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException NRefEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception is => {0}", NRefEx);
    }
}
```

This assumes the format of the lines to be:

```
    <ErrCode> <DefectName> <Action> <JudeTime> <UserName>
```

If the order is different you need to adjust the indexes into the data array.